# PlayOnLinux won't start

Tags: python, playonlinux

When I click on the icon nothing happens. In the terminal when I run playonlinux I get the following.

```
ImportError: No module named wxversion
Looking for python... 2.7.7 - selected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainwindow.py", line 31, in <module>
    import wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to install `wxpython`.  Use the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

Comment: I ran the command and it told me that I already have the most recent version.

Comment: That's odd.  Go to a new terminal window, type `python` then once in the python shell, type `import wxversion`.  Make sure that you're running a Python 2.7.x version.  If that spits out no errors then you should be fine.

Comment: I got `Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun 13 2014, 15:15:49) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wxversion
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named wxversion`

Comment: Okay, that's odd if it says that you have the most recent version.  Try doing `sudo apt-get purge python-wxgtk2.8`, then run the `install` command again.

Comment: I purged then re-installed but I'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: There is also the `python-wxversion` package you can try installing.  If that doesn't fix it, there's also the option of building from source: http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython_from_source

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu and now it works normally.

Comment: Installing `python-wxversion` solved it for me (other steps didn't work)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is two years old, but what worked for me in 2016 was:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxtools
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed any python versions from source , then also you can face this problem.

So

Follow these instructions and things should work out:

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>(Open Applications menu, Accessories, Terminal). Run `sudo nautilus` (no quotes), giving your password when prompted.

Using the file browser that opens, navigate to `/usr/local/bin/`

Delete the file called `python`

Go to `/usr/bin/`

Right-click the file called 'python' and click copy. Paste it into `/usr/local/bin/`

Go back to '/usr/bin/' and copy 'python2.6' and paste it into `/usr/local/bin/`

Do the same with the file called `python2.6-config`

[Total credit goes to ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1658489)

Comment: I have python 2.7. Do I need to download 2.6 or is that fine for this?

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but if you still have this issue is is solved here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/903047/676362

Answer (score 1):

It works for me when I do the following:

1. comment any PATH settings related to another python path in my ~/.bashrc. Such as the line with "export PATH="/home/***/anaconda2/bin;$PAHT"
2. restart a terminal and run playonlinux.

Comment: Perfect solution mate

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My problem was that python-wxversion was on version 3, so I downgraded it to version 2.8.

To do that, I used Synaptic package manager, if you don't have it installed, open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Open Synaptic, then in the search box type `python-wxversion`, then click on the package, then click on the menu `Package` and select `Force version`. A window should appear asking you to select the version you want, choose the 2.8 version and click on `Force version` and confirm if asked. After that, Synaptic will download and install (downgrade) the package. When done, try to run Playonlinux again.

Comment: The force version button is grayed out for me.

Comment: Use the repository from the Playonlnux website and try again: https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html  For the Trusty version
Type the following commands:

wget -q "http://deb.playonlinux.com/public.gpg" -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo wget http://deb.playonlinux.com/playonlinux_trusty.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/playonlinux.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install playonlinux