# Playonlinux asks to install Python

Tags: wine, python, playonlinux, wxpython

just few days ago I installed other version of Python on Ubuntu (I need it for coding). Installation of Python went pretty much smoothly, but when I try to launch League Of Legends I get a problem. I've tried to google this problem, but didn't find any working solution.

That's what I get if I run Playonlinux on Terminal:

```
    Looking for python... 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit) - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit) - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.6... 
Looking for python2... 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit) - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in <module>
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Please install python before trying to run this program
```

Also I've found [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498834/playonlinux-wont-start) answers here, but they didn't solve my problem.

Is there a way to fix it somehow?

P.s. Please don't suggest to reinstall Ubuntu, because I'll have to install this version of Python anyway.

Thank you!!!

Comment: So did you install the other version of python from source or using `apt-get`? Try running `python -V` to see what python version you're using

Comment: Yeah, I did, but not much of that. 
Now I'm using Python 2.7.9 with Anaconda. 
I think the problem is this version is too new for Playonlinux, m? @Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get install python-wxversion`.

Comment: Done that. Also tried to reinstall it, but still the same. @Jamie

Comment: This won't work, if OP installed a different version of Python, that doesn't pick up the Python modules installed by the package manager.