# PlayOnLinux won't launch

Tags: 16.04, wine, python, playonlinux

I've installed wine using [this](https://youtu.be/1me6ebGWKEo) tutorial and installed the 'trusty' version of PlayOnLinux with the terminal commands from [here](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html). I tried running PlayOnLinux, it would appear on the launcher, pulse for a few seconds and then went away. I then tried opening it via command line and it showed this:

```
Looking for python... 2.7.12 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in 
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.12 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in 
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.6... 
Looking for python2... 2.7.12 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in 
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Please install python before trying to run this program
```

I tried using the solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498834/playonlinux-wont-start) but it didn't work for me (outdated code maybe?), it just showed

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-wxgtk2.8' has no installation candidate
```

Someone in the same question said that `sudo apt-get install python-wxtools` fixed it for them but it tells me that I have the newest version installed.

Comment: I'm writing this in an answer because I can't add a comment. I was researching this issue, and it happens to me also. I believe the issue lies in a "too new" install of WX. The official Ubuntu repositories have a newer version of WX that what PlayOnLinux needs. Hope this helps, and good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I managed to get PlayOnLinux running with both python **2.7.9** (installed alongside POL) and **2.7.12** on the same machine:

First, you have to locate where python 2.7.9 is installed, mine is `/usr/bin/python`

After that, edit `/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python` (you might need root-privileges)

Replace these lines:

- `next_python "python"`
- `next_python "python2.7"`

with `next_python "/usr/bin/python"`.

Save & exit. Run `playonlinux` again.

Voilà.

Comment: Godspeed my friend. This answer still helps me today

Answer (score 0):

Download the lattest PlayOnLinux.deb from the site and install that:

```
wget https://www.playonlinux.com/script_files/PlayOnLinux/4.2.10/PlayOnLinux_4.2.10.deb
sudo dpkg -i PlayOnLinux_4.2.10.deb
```

Sadly the PlayOnLinux site is stucked on 14.04 but their deb file is compatible with current ubuntu versions and somehow it's newer than the repo has.

If the installation fails because missing packages then use the -f flag in the apt to install dependecies:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: It still tells me to install python.

Comment: @Imthi Hmm, strange. For the wxPython you need the libwxbase2.8.0 package.

Comment: When I checked it with synaptic it showed that the newest version was 3.0.2 (which it says is the version I have installed. I'm extremely confused as to what I have done wrong.

Comment: Yes, the newest version is 3.x, I have it installed as well, but thats a libwxbase3.0 and libwxbase3.0-dev package.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you're trying to say. Are you trying to say that libwxbase3.0 will not work with playonlinux?