# Playonlinux won't start. Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, playonlinux

When I try to launch playonlinux, nothing happens graphically.

When I try to load it with terminal I get:

```
Looking for python... 2.7.13 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in 
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.13 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in 
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Looking for python2.6... 
Looking for python2... 2.7.13 - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/playonlinux/python/check_python.py", line 1, in 
    import os, wxversion
ImportError: No module named wxversion
failed tests
Please install python before trying to run this program
```

When I run:

```
python --version
```

It shows I have python 2.7.13

I've also tried using solutions from the following link without any luck.

> [PlayOnLinux won't start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498834/playonlinux-wont-start)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else who had this issue, here's your solution..

If you try to run playonlinux and recieve this error:

> ```
> ImportError: No module named wxversion
> failed tests 
> Please install python before trying to run this program
> ```

Edit this file:

> /usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python

And change the following from:

> ```
>             next_python "python"
>             next_python "python2.7"
>             next_python "python2.6"
>             next_python "python2"
>             next_python "none"
> ```

to:

> ```
>             next_python "/usr/bin/python" #<<This line was added
>             next_python "python"
>             next_python "python2.7"
>             next_python "python2.6"
>             next_python "python2"
>             next_python "none"
> ```

And that's it!

Comment: This answer is GOLD.