# playonlinux doesn´t start

Tags: lubuntu, python, playonlinux

I have problems starting playonlinux and wonder whether you could help.

I have playonlinux v. 4.2.12. Yet when trying to start the programme via the terminal I get the following message:

```
Looking for python... 2.7.12 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk2
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python: Zeile 58:  9558 Ungültiger 
Maschinenbefehl   "$POL_PYTHON" "$POLDIR/python/check_python.py"
failed tests
Looking for python2.7... 2.7.12 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk2
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python: Zeile 58:  9564 Ungültiger 
Maschinenbefehl   "$POL_PYTHON" "$POLDIR/python/check_python.py"
failed tests
Looking for python2.6...
Looking for python2... 2.7.12 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk2
/usr/share/playonlinux/bash/find_python: Zeile 58:  9571 Ungültiger 
Maschinenbefehl   "$POL_PYTHON" "$POLDIR/python/check_python.py"
failed tests
Please install python before trying to run this program
```

According to the output of the terminal it seems that  python ist´t installed - which simply is not true.
Here are my python versions:

```
ii  python                                        2.7.11-1                                     
amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default 
version)
ii  python2.7                                   2.7.12-
1ubuntu0~16.04.1      amd64        Interactive high-level object-
oriented language (version 2.7)
ii  python3                                      3.5.1-3                                       
amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default 
python3 version)
ii  python3.5                                   3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3        
amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (version 
3.5)
```

I´ve already looked on page  [PlayOnLinux won't start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498834/playonlinux-wont-start/903715) but nothing worked.
Neither did the workaround presented on [Playonlinux won't start. Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903004/playonlinux-wont-start-ubuntu-16-04/903047#903047).
Is there any way to get playonlinux started?

Tnx a lot. Rosika

P.S.:
my system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, 64bit

Comment: If you dont get help here try the playonlinux forums - https://www.playonlinux.com/en/forums.html

Comment: Hi, tnx for the suggestion. I already did that ( https://www.playonlinux.com/en/topic-15530-playonlinux_wonat_start.html ). Yet no answer so far.

Comment: Remove all of PlayOnLinux and install the `wine` command that is a great alternative to install and run any Windows app, here is my explanation : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and everything is working fine

OS : lubuntu 19.04 
playonlinux + ms-office 2010

But - these are the steps i followed:

1. Use Muon (builtin with lubuntu) to install playonlinux (this automatically installs wine for you)
2. add i386 architecture  [this is imp for msoffice 2010]
3. then install wine32

Then proceed to install your ms office.  [from directory or from mounted iso]

It will do a few intermediate installations [fonts, dotnet bla bla] and also a few error screens. Just wait. At the end choose "Do not send any bugs as feedback" [as mentioned on playonlinux and wine pages]

That is it.

Also i want to write a few lines why people still use MS office when libreoffice is available.

1. Many job places use MS-office / outlook as corporate policy. So, those folks want to do some work at home [possibly without/ with internet], and they need outlook with all the emails; with PST archives.
2. MS word for preparing reports or updating reports that were already developed in a specific format. Tables, diagrams etc won't work that well in other software

enjoy 19.04. No worries for another year!